# How to properly inject dependencies in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm having some issues with dependency injection that I'd like to clearify. The first thing to mention is a dependency injection container (DIC) I implemented, which is capable of registering and resolving dependencies through constructors using *ReflectionClass*.

```
$container = new DiC;
$container->register('session', 'CSession');
$container->register('response', 'CResponse');
$container->register('model', 'CSomeModel');
$container->register('view', 'CSomeView');
$container->register('controller', 'CSomeController');
```

A dependent controller:

```
class CSomeController extends CController
{
  public function __construct(CSomeModel $model, CSomeView $view)
  {
    // assign arguments here
  }
}
```

Now the controller can be instantiated through DIC:

```
$controller = $container->resolve('controller');
```

I like this approach because it is automated and descriptive, however class CController depends on specific classes CSomeModel, CSomeView which is bad. **MVC triads should be instantiated independently** - I cannot pass COtherView to CSomeController for example.

My second guess is to inject the DIC:

```
class CSomeController extends CController
{
  public function __construct(DiC $dic)
  {
    // resolve dependencies through $dic
  }
}
```

This one makes DiC object global, many people argue this is not the way to implement DI.

**Is there a third way that eliminates the weaknesses from both approaches?**

Comment: Would you mind posting your `DiC` class?

Comment: You should take a look on how [Laravel4](http://four.laravel.com/docs/ioc) is handling that, specially the "Binding An Interface To An Implementation" session. You can find the relevant source at [Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php)

Comment: Symfony2 uses a very solid DI component that is based on Java Spring...this is similar to what you doing .. taking a step further.. http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your looking for "auto-wiring", switch to Interfaces and implement your concrete Model/View/etc. classes against that interface.  That way you could use reflection to pair up both sides.

It would also make sense to have a mechanism for explicitly specifying dependencies at the container level.

Comment: Is there a tutorial somewhere on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think both approaches are relevant. In case you want to be more flexible in the first approach you could change the constructor to have a parent class as a dependency. Then every object that inherits from that parent class could be injected. I.e.

```
class CSomeModel extends AbstractCModel {}
class CSomeOtherModel extends AbstractCModel {}

public function __construct(AbstractCModel $model, AbstractCView $view) {}
```

The second approach is suitable if you need to access factories. I.e. if you need to access multiple instances of the same object.

Comment: IoC class resolves dependencies by using PHP Reflection. By injecting abstract classes I loose automation...

Comment: An interface would be better than an abstract class.